# How to globalize my Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, internationalization, globalization

I have a simple Rails application (not even database driven). And basically I want to make it support two languages. My approach to this is to have **two little flags** in the footer, one of GB (for **English**) and one of Germany (for **German**). When the *User clicks on one, the language of the site changes to the corresponding language of the country flag*.

I have my [ en.yml ] and [ de.yml ] all setup, and I have **used their keys in all my views**, and I have even *tested* that they work by swapping the [ config.i18n.default_locale ] property between [ en ] and [ de ] in [ config/application.rb ]. All works well in that regard.

I am stuck however on how I can achieve the language changing mechanism. I have created a controller called [ Language ] and in it I have defined a method called [ Set ] but other than that, it is pretty much blank, here is what I think should happen:

```
class LanguageController < ApplicationController
  def set
    I18n.locale = params[:lang]
    redirect_to(:controller => 'home', :action => 'index')
  end
end
```

The above doesn't seem to work. When I call the [ **/language/set?lang="de"** ] the localized strings change to the **keys** not the actual German translated text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
I18n.locale = params[:lang]
```

does not persist across requests, so when you redirect (= a new request) it reverts back to English.

You should save the language setting in a session:

```
class LanguageController < ApplicationController
  def set
    session[:lang] = params[:lang].to_sym
    redirect_to(:controller => 'home', :action => 'index')
  end
end
```

And check the session on each request. You can do this in a `before_filter` in your `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController
  before_filter :set_language

  def set_language
    I18n.locale = session[:lang] if session[:lang]
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you Mischa. I was thinking about that too, but did not do cause in the docs it was advising against using sessions for this purpose. In any case, I have done as you suggested, but the translated text still doesn't show, only the keys, show not the translated value !

Comment: @Ciwan - I guess you should call `.to_sym` on `params[:lang]` to make it a symbol instead of a string. Also, are you calling `/language/set?lang="de"` or `/language/set?lang=de`? It should be the latter.

Comment: I saw the remark about not using sessions in the guide. I guess it make sense. If you want to avoid sessions you have to keep the `?lang=de` in the URL the whole time. There is a (paid) [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/138-i18n-revised) that explains how to do this. Despite the warning, using sessions is the easiest solution.

Comment: Thanks very much. That fixed it. Plus I was being silly and using double quotes around the supplied lang parameter value.